# JQuery - toggle selected row depending on classname and data attr. (data-tag-id)

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I have been reading / searching many questions re. table row and toggle, I have not found why my Jquery is not working. Here is my case:

**What I want to achieve**

onclick of any td in row with className 'show-tag', show the tr with className 'edit-tag' where data-tagid is the same as the data-tagid of the td clicked (show using display: table-row (not block)) and hide all rows with className 'edit-tag' and different data-tagid.

**Table**

```
<tr data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 1</td>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 2</td>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 3</td>
    <td class="delete-ban">data 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='1', class='edit-tag'>
    <td>onclick of any td in row with show-tag class AND same data-tag (1) show this tr (using display: table-row) and hide rows with className edit-tag and different data-tagid</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 1</td>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 2</td>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 3</td>
    <td class="delete-ban">data 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='2', class='edit-tag'>
    <td>onclick of any td in row with show-tag class AND same data-tag (1) show this tr (using display: table-row) and hide rows with className edit-tag and different data-tagid</td>
</tr>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("td.show-tag").on("click", function(event) { 
    if ($(this).is("td")) { 
    var tagId = $(this).closest("td").data("tagid"); 
    var editRow = $("tr.edit-tag.[data-tagid=" + tagId +"]"); 
    $editRow.toggle(); 
} 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.edit-tag {
    display: none;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `.hide()` all the `tr.edit-tag` except clicked. For that use `.not()`

```
$("td.show-tag").on("click", function(event) { 
  var tagId = $(this).data('tagid');
  $('tr.edit-tag').not($('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']')).hide();
  $('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').toggle();
});
```

```js
$("td.show-tag").on("click", function(event) { 
  var tagId = $(this).data('tagid');
  //console.log(tagId);
  $('tr.edit-tag').not($('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']')).hide();
  $('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').toggle();
});
```

```css
.edit-tag {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 1</td>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 2</td>
    <td data-tagid='1', class='show-tag'>data 3</td>
    <td class="delete-ban">data 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='1', class='edit-tag'>
    <td>1onclick of any td in row with show-tag class AND same data-tag (1) show this tr (using display: table-row) and hide rows with className edit-tag and different data-tagid</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 1</td>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 2</td>
    <td data-tagid='2', class='show-tag'>data 3</td>
    <td class="delete-ban">data 4</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tagid='2', class='edit-tag'>
    <td>2onclick of any td in row with show-tag class AND same data-tag (1) show this tr (using display: table-row) and hide rows with className edit-tag and different data-tagid</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Follow on question: this uses `display: block`. How can I get it to set `display: table-row` ?

Comment: You can use `.css()` in jQuery.

Comment: how please? like so ... `$('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').toggle().css(display: table-row);` ?

Comment: I think when I toggle, I can see in console `display: table-row` already.

But to do that `$('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').css(display: table-row); `but that won't work toggle again.

Comment: what do you mean with "but that won't work toggle again" ?

Comment: What exactly you wants to do ? `toggle()` of `.css()` for show and hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126020/discussion-between-dimitri-de-ruiter-and-loading).